OAuth2 in development (Sandbox)
I'm currently developing OAuth2 integration for a website of an organization which internally uses Google Workspace (for Non-Profits). Login to the website should only be possible with Google accounts from their domain (and only if the users have a specific permission to edit contents on the website).
I found the documentation and several posts here which say that one has to create separate projects for development, staging and production and therefore separate OAuth credentials.
What I could not find yet is, if Google has kind of a sandbox environment for developers to implement and test OAuth integration. First I don't want to develop with production data (user accounts in Google Workspace), especially when adding custom attributes or similar. Second I need to test different workflows (automatic user creation in the website with role mapping, what happens if a user looses to required permissions and tries to sign into the website). For this I need multiple defined users with different data in Google as they should produce different mappings, roles and assignments in the website.

You can try the OAuth 2.0 Playground here. It provides the sandbox environment for what you are trying to achieve.

I know the OAuth 2.0 playground. But I don't see how to solve the following questions/issues:

I don't want to develop with production data (user accounts in Google Workspace). In that sandbox I still need a Google account from the workspace.
I get the request to execute, but can't execute it in the browser to retrieve the data and check which attributes I get with which scope.
That doesn't help to implement/test external integrations, like Drupal modules or Wordpress plugins.

